# Where are travis logs dumped

Tags: travis-ci

I am trying to test an R package on travis for linux compatibility. Since it fails, I need to access the logs. I added in .travis.yml

```
after_failure:
```

- "cat /home/travis/build/xxxx/yyy/yyy.Rcheck/00check.log"
  - ./travis-tool.sh dump_logs

This prints the logs but for the actual file it refers to

/home/travis/build/xxxxx/yyy/yyy.Rcheck/00check.log

Can someone tell me how to retrieve the file?

marco

Answer (score 1):

You can use our artifacts support to upload the log to an S3 bucket: http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/uploading-artifacts/

Comment: Thanks. I don't know what an S3 bucket is. I guess that the answer is that the "home" directory is not directly accessible?